# In visual studio C++ project, how do I add to "headers search path" and "source list"

Tags: c++, socket.io

I'm trying to add socket.io into my C++ project, but I'm lacking some understanding of what the steps are asking for. It's asking me to add a few folders into

1. headers search path
2. include into source list

I'm guessing that it's in the properties, but I cannot find these 2 terms in there. Please enlighten me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look in the VC++ Directories page (the "Include directories" setting) or the C/C++ -> General page ("Additional include directories" setting).

Comment: so that is for "include into source list", or "headers search path", or both?